# Decompressed a .xz file and now it has no extension and is not a directory

Tags: linux, compression, tar, opensuse, xz

I had a directory of files that I compressed using:

```shell
tar -cvJf my_directory.xz my_directory
```

Now I've gone to decompress it using:

```shell
xz -dv my_directory.xz my_directory
```

and the resulting file is simply `my_directory`. It has no extension and it's not a directory, but the size corresponds exactly with what the original directory should be in its decompressed state.

```shell
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user computer 1.1G Jun  8 12:16 my_directory
```

What did I do wrong, and is there a way to remedy this if I no longer have access to the original uncompressed directory?

Comment: I'm realizing now that most likely the first mistake I made was in compressing a *directory* as only a `.xz` file instead of a tarball (`.tar.xz`).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP admitted he made simple mistake (in comment)

Comment: Why are you using `xz` to decompress it now? Did you try `tar -x`?

Comment: Honest answer? I forgot that I used `tar` in the first place. But that leads to another question—if you use `tar` to compress a tarball, but don't include `.tar` in the file extension of the desired filename, does it still compress as a tarball?

Comment: What do you mean "you forgot"? You listed commands above. Not that it'll help likely, I'm just not following. I wouldn't close this BTW as I'm curious if it's still solvable.

Comment: I decompressed the `.xz` file using `xz` (and not `tar`) because I forgot that I originally compressed it using `tar` (which I did weeks ago). I had already decompressed it prior to writing.

Comment: For future reference: `file` is the right starting point when dealing with files of unknown format. `file my_directory` would probably tell you it's a tar archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to just revert the actions with:

1. `xz -zv my_directory my_directory.xz` (`-z` compress flag instead of `-d` decompress)
2. `tar -xvJf my_directory.xz` (`-x` extract flag instead of `-c` create)

Which is something to always keep in mind as a possibility in terms of reversible operations such as compression.

### What happened wrong here and why did `tar -xf my_directory` work?

Basically, `xz -d` simply decompressed the `.tar.xz` archive that you made, but still left it as a tarball `.tar` archive called `my_directory` without the extension as instructed.

You could have also renamed the file to `anything.tar` and then it would open correctly in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out simply running `tar -xf my_directory` on the "decompressed file" successfully decompresses it into the original `my_directory/` directory.